# How can I open an xls file, save it, and then close it all in java?

Tags: java, excel, vbscript, apache-poi, xls

How can I open an xls file, save it, and then close it all in java?

I currently have a workaround where I make java write a vbs script that does the same thing

```
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excel.Workbooks.Open("path to xls file")
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
excel.quit
```

Java then runs this vbs script by passing the path to cmd

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cscript " + decodedPath3 + filename + ".vbs");
```

and then I delete the vbs I created

Is there a way I can replicate these steps just in java?

I've done a lot of reading about POI and I'm not sure how to do this simple task just with java.

note - the VBS script doesn't actually make excel open up and display the sheet making it fast. I need java to do the same thing.

In response to the comments about http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ Would this work?

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.util.Date; 
import jxl.*; 
import jxl.write.*; 


Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls"));
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("myfile.xls"), workbook);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you need a third party library to do it. There are various available both free and not free. Look at this project on SourceForge for example:

```
jexcelapi.sourceforge.net
```

Nothing necessarily wrong with your solution except that it will not be portable off of a Windows machine with the VBA runtime libraries installed.

Comment: at the bottom of my post I put some example code- would that function exactly the same way as my vbs script?